# Understanding different Referrer-policy and what is sent when

Tags: php, http, http-referer, referrer-policy

I am creating a class (es) in php to validate if `referrers` received in the headers adhere to the `Referrer-policy` set for the document.

I have tried to create a table which will tell me when a referer is sent and what to expect in them. However I could not find relevant information for the following cases:

1. `origin-when-cross-origin` - what to expect for same origin requests when the protocol improves
2. `strict-origin` - what to expect for same origin requests when the protocol improves

[Reference Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#directives)

The below table shows the current status of where I am.

| referrer-policy | `so` & `ps` | `so` & `pi` | `so` & `pd` | `co` & `ps` | `co` & `pi` | `co` & `pd` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *no-referrer* | none | none | none | none | none | none |
| *no-referrer-when-downgrade* | comUrl | comUrl | none | comUrl | comUrl | none |
| *origin* | origin | origin | origin | origin | origin | origin |
| *origin-when-cross-origin* | comUrl | ?? | origin | origin | origin | origin |
| *same-origin* | comUrl | comUrl | comUrl | none | none | none |
| *strict-origin* | origin | ?? | none | origin | origin | none |
| *strict-origin-when-cross-origin* | comUrl | comUrl | none | orgin | origin | none |
| *unsafe-url* | comUrl | comUrl | comUrl | comUrl | comUrl | comUrl |

Please read the table as per the following legends

- `so` -> same origin,
- `co` -> cross origin,
- `ps` -> protocol same (`http -> http`, `https -> https`),
- `pi` -> protocol improves (`http -> https`)
- `pd` -> protocol downgrades (`https -> http` or `https -> file` and I assume `http -> file` too),
- `Origin` -> `scheme`, `hostname`, and `port`
- `comUrl` -> `origin`, `path`, and `querystring` (basically skips `user`, `pass` and `fragment` ie. anything after #)

So what is the expected response in the two cases? Also am I correct in assuming a protocol downgrade when an `http` page makes a request to `file`

Comment: I don’t have an answer, but I hope you are testing this in multiple browsers from multiple eras, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Well this is from the docs only. I have not tested these yet. Is there no place they have documented the behavior across browsers. I mean installing that many versions may take susbtantial time and effort. Is that the only way to get to the bottom of this?